# Siri Accounts Faults in MAC OS Catalina (10.15.6): (Process Demon Faults: accountsd + deleted + locationd) VERY slow CPU!

Tags: catalina, activity-monitor

I'm seeing a common Mac OS Catalina (10.15.6) fault with accountsd/deleted and Siri? (com.apple.siri.e)?  It seems to be extremely serious!  Does anyone know the cause or solution for this?  My computer seems to be overheating a lot and has very very high CPU usage!?  Is this because of overheating or something else with Siri and a demon?

**OS Version:       Mac OS X 10.15.6 (Build 19G73)**

Is this a possible "malware" or virus?  Or some bug with SQLITE?

**ACCOUNTS DAEMON (AccountsDaemon):**

***FAULT MESSAGES:***

```
"TIMING: Daemon save took 1.291293025016785"
"Completed account save: YES - (null)."
Unentitled access by client 'com.apple.siri.e' 
(selector: accountsWithAccountType:handler:)
"Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9"
"Cannot check access to a private account type: <private>"
"No TCC state found: <private>, <private>"
AMSAccountNotificationPlugin: [1E2C940E] Skipping biometrics update (not authed)
"Client <private> is not allowed to access accounts of type <private>."
Unentitled access by client 'CallHistoryPlugi' (selector: accountsWithAccountType:handler:)
"Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9"
AMSAccountNotificationPlugin: [1E2C940E] Refusing to post a com.apple.itunesstored.accountschanged notification because nothing on the account actually changed.
AMSAccountStoreCache: [1E2C940E] An ACAccountStore has no associated media type. Returning the default media type for the current process. accountStore = AMSAccountStoreCache | defaultMediaType = com.apple.AppleMediaServices.accountmediatype.itunes
"Cannot check access to a private account type: <private>"
"No TCC state found: <private>, <private>"
"Client <private> is not allowed to access accounts of type <private>."
```

**Hardware Overview:**

```
  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,3
  Processor Name:   Quad-Core Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.8 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
  Memory:   16 GB
  Boot ROM Version: 162.0.0.0.0
  SMC Version (system): 2.19f12
```

**SCREEN SHOT:**
**System Console "OS" FAULT MESSAGE:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

What suggestions do people have about this problem?

Thanks!
Asher
:)

Here is a memory profile... from the command "kextstat -l -k | awk '{n = sprintf("%d", $4); print n, $6}' | sort -n"

```
901120 com.apple.kec.corecrypto
999424 com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily
1024000 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily
1036288 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily
1212416 com.apple.filesystems.apfs
1294336 com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib
1425408 com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family
1470464 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul
1753088 com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal
2981888 com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman
8196096 com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC
```

here is a "top" command output...

```
PID  COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH   #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPR PGRP PPID

458  deleted      70.9 17:27.80 8/1   7/1  79    4596K  0B     0B   458  1
570  Console      51.2 23:14.11 15    11   1243- 382M-  6460K  0B   570  1
573  diagnosticd  28.5 21:18.62 8     7    529   10M    0B     0B   573  1
303  sysmond      22.1 03:40.38 3     2/1  30    3820K  0B     0B   303  1
237  WindowServer 19.0 18:17.49 11    4    1862+ 340M   22M-   0B   237  1
682  Terminal     11.9 00:13.53 8/1   1    305-  29M-   5944K+ 0B   682  1
501  Activity Mon 9.6  21:51.42 5/2   3    1392+ 85M+   10M    0B   501  1
153  hidd         9.1  03:23.60 6     3    221   4476K- 0B     0B   153  1
819  top          8.0  00:01.29 1/1   0    28    3752K+ 0B     0B   819  684
0    kernel_task  6.3  04:49.91 171/8 0    0     66M    0B     0B   0    0
111  powerd       2.0  00:42.87 3     2    116   2592K  0B     0B   111  1
```

Comment: That's a lot of data, but it's not really clear how it fits together and how it relates to whatever problem you actually have. The system seems to be under quite some load though. Can you focus the question on describing the actual problem you want to solve, and a screenshot of Activity Monitor's CPU tab sorted by %CPU (and showing the processes using most CPU currently)? The rest of the data may or may not be required, the question would be easier to read if you don't include it without explanation. You can always add more if people ask for it in comments.

Comment: Yes, its a very complex problem.. I did clean up a few of the images and also simplified the "top" and memory footprint details.. :)

Answer (score 1):

There was a memory leak in the kernel in your version of 10.5.6 - please update immediately to the supplemental update. Build 19G2021 should fix this issue.

Not just the supplemental update is needed, but Supplemental Update 2.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210589
- https://eclecticlight.co/2020/08/16/last-week-on-my-mac-apple-leak/

Comment: so your suggesting this is a "global" problem with apples software? and not my specific system?  How did you see this problem in your specific system?

Answer (score 0):

the "locationd" errors are due to "uninstalling" applications and needing to "manually" remove them from apple security infrastructure.

for example, if you no longer use a "weather" app and uninstall it but have authorized it with "location security" you still need to remove it from apple settings.  here are some screen shots of what this looks like...

[image]

and then "manually" remove it... (unfortunately removing the app into the "trash" isn't all thats needed for many many applications?)

[image]

NOTE: there are "other" bugs.. however this was one... it maybe a general apple OS security flaw with uninstalling applications on MacOS that use "location services" demons??  :(

Comment: Or there’s a memory leak that the supplemental update fixes. https://mrmacintosh.com/catalina-10-15-6-supplemental-update-19g2021-released/ and https://eclecticlight.co/2020/08/16/last-week-on-my-mac-apple-leak/ it’s so rare for these to get out, I can’t recall the last time a legit memory leak shipped in the release channel by Apple.